# Xcode 6: Label in Table Cell won't expand / display longer text upon expansion / line up with cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

**The Problem:**

I've got a label in a table cell as follows:

[image]

*EDIT:* While the tableview does not use AutoLayout, the xib for the cell does. This is what it looks like:

[image]

Now, the "..." means the review (the text) is too long to be displayed. The user can then click on the cell, which would expand the cell and the label downwards, which would then show the rest of the text.

Here's the code for the `heightForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    if (tableView == self.rateAndReviewView.ratingsTable) {
        BOOL isSelected = [self.selectedIndexPaths containsObject:indexPath];

        CGFloat maxHeight = MAXFLOAT;
        CGFloat minHeight = 40.0f;

        if (isSelected){
            CGFloat constrainHeight = isSelected?maxHeight:minHeight;
            CGFloat constrainWidth  = tableView.frame.size.width - 20.0f;
            //
            SQLReview *review = [reviewsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            NSString *text       = review.comment;
            CGSize constrainSize = CGSizeMake(constrainWidth, constrainHeight);

            CGSize labelSize = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0f]
                                  constrainedToSize:constrainSize
                                  lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

            CGFloat labelHeight = labelSize.height;

            return MAX(labelHeight+20, 100.0f);
        } else {
            minHeight = 100.0f;
            return  minHeight;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the code for the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (tableView == self.rateAndReviewView.ratingsTable) {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        VenueReviewCell *cell = (VenueReviewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if(cell==nil){
            cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ReviewCell" owner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        }

        [cell.contentView.layer setBorderWidth:0.5f];
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        SQLReview *review = [reviewsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.usernameLabel.text = (review.user_name == nil) ? @"" : review.user_name;
        cell.datetimeLabel.text = (review.datetime == nil) ? @"" : [review.datetime substringToIndex:10];
        cell.commentLabel.text = (review.comment == nil) ? @"" : review.comment;
        cell.commentLabel2.text = (review.comment == nil) ? @"" : review.comment;

        float overallScore = (review.overall == nil) ? 0.0f : [review.overall floatValue];

        NSArray *overallImageViewArray = @[cell.overallStarImageView1, cell.overallStarImageView2, cell.overallStarImageView3, cell.overallStarImageView4, cell.overallStarImageView5];

        if([selectedIndexPaths containsObject:indexPath]) {
            cell.commentLabel.hidden = YES;
            cell.commentLabel2.hidden = NO;

            CGSize commentLabelComputeSize = [cell.commentLabel2.text sizeWithFont:cell.commentLabel2.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(cell.commentLabel2.frame.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX) lineBreakMode:cell.commentLabel2.lineBreakMode];

            CGFloat commentLabelHeightOffset = (commentLabelComputeSize.height - cell.commentLabel2.frame.size.height > 0) ? (commentLabelComputeSize.height - cell.commentLabel2.frame.size.height) : 0;

            cell.commentLabel2.frame = CGRectMake(cell.commentLabel2.frame.origin.x, cell.commentLabel2.frame.origin.y, cell.commentLabel2.frame.size.width, cell.commentLabel2.frame.size.height + commentLabelHeightOffset);

            cell.commentLabel2.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
            cell.commentLabel2.numberOfLines = 0;

        } else {
            cell.commentLabel.hidden = NO;
            cell.commentLabel2.hidden = YES;
        }

        [CommonUtilities displayStarRatingsWithScore:overallScore starImageViewArray:overallImageViewArray];

        return cell;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

The `isSelected` part from `heightForRowAtIndexPath` does work, and the table cell does visibly expand on tap, but the text remains the same - at least, as tested on iOS 7+ devices.

*EDIT:* I also logged out the values of `cell.commentLabel2.frame`, by adding this:

```
NSLog(@"VenueTabViewController: cellForRow: contains indexpath %@, size: %@", indexPath, NSStringFromCGRect(cell.commentLabel2.frame));
```

in both the `if` and `else` of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, and it shows the following:

On first tap:
VenueTabViewController: cellForRow: contains indexpath  {length = 2, path = 0 - 1}, size: {{20, 31}, {285, 60.579999999999998}}

On second tap:
VenueTabViewController: cellForRow: contains indexpath  {length = 2, path = 0 - 2}, size: {{20, 31}, {285, 21}}

So it does change in size.

**What I tried:**

I googled this, and found out that `[string sizeWithFont:[UIFont       systemFontOfSize:15.0f] constrainedToSize:constrainSize       lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];` has been depreciated. So    instead, I replaced the lines relating to it above with:

```
CGSize labelSize = [text sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0f]}]; 
CGFloat labelHeight = ceilf(labelSize.height);
```

Which not only failed to work, it also stopped the cell from expanding, which I thought might be a step backwards.

I also tried adding the following, because why not:

```
VenueReviewCell *cell = (VenueReviewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if(cell==nil){
    cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ReviewCell" owner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
}

[cell.commentLabel sizeToFit];
```

But it's still a nope.

Then, I simply replaced `commentLabelHeightOffset` with 100, just to test if anything will change:

```
cell.commentLabel2.frame = CGRectMake(cell.commentLabel2.frame.origin.x, cell.commentLabel2.frame.origin.y, cell.commentLabel2.frame.size.width, cell.commentLabel2.frame.size.height + commentLabelHeightOffset);
```

Nothing happened.

*EDIT:* Here's what I did that finally gained traction - I removed the AutoLayout on the cells, as per the suggestion of saif. And now, while the cells do expand, and the labels along with it, for some reason I get this:

[image]

I checked the code, and the X and Y of the label frame aren't changed (just the frame height) and the text has no "new lines" before the actual text.

Can I have some help please?

Comment: are you using auto layouts

Comment: Did you try `label.numberOfLines = 0` ?

Comment: @saif, nope. I tried it. It only made it worse by preventing the table from loading completely. For reference, the table and everything in it is actually in a separate nib, and loaded separately.

Comment: @orkenstein, tried it just now. Didn't work when I put it in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Should I put it anywhere else?

Comment: @zack_falcon, **before** `[cell.commentLabel sizeToFit]`?
Try `willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` instead.

Comment: @orkenstein, I re-added those back into the code, in the order you specified. Didn't work either. As for `willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`, where do I put that?

Comment: @zack_falcon, posted another approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, Set the frame to desc label in cell for row(depending on text size), and reload the table view when you want to expand the cell.

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID forIndexPath:indexPath];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellID];
    //code to add desc label
}

CGSize suggestedSize = [descriptionText sizeWithFont:descLabel.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(descLabel.frame.size.width, FLT_MAX) lineBreakMode:descLabel.lineBreakMode];
float padding = 20;
[descLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(padding, CGRectGetMaxY(nameLabel.frame), CGRectGetWidth(tableView.frame)-(2*padding), suggestedSize.height)];
```

if you are using auto layouts in custom cell then

1. Keep a back up, and uncheck auto layouts
2. select iPhone in drop down and select Disable size class

If there is a problem with row height,

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{    

    CGSize suggestedSize = [descriptionText sizeWithFont:descLabel.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(descLabel.frame.size.width, FLT_MAX) lineBreakMode:descLabel.lineBreakMode];
    float heightOfRow = CGRectGetMaxY(nameLabel.frame)+suggestedSize.height+5; // height of name label(as it is single line supported) + height of desc label + bottom padding
    return heightOfRow;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: My apologies, but upon checking the cell nib  itself, it is using Auto layout, in reference to your earlier comment; it is the tableview that doesn't. Does that change anything?

Comment: yes, it may be the reason, try removing auto layouts for custom cell

Comment: Unchecking the Auto-layout gives the following warning:
Using Size Classes Requires Auto Layout - Disabling size classes will limit this document to storing data for a single device family. The data for the size class best representing the targeted device will be retained, and all other data will be removed.

Comment: Keep a back up, and uncheck auto layouts, then select iPhone in drop down and select `Disable size class`.

Comment: Wow. I had no idea how that worked, but, it did, somewhat - on shorter texts (but still longer than normal), it works perfectly, thanks! On texts in the form of a paragraph, though, the label either gets filled with empty space at the top, or actually moves down too much. The result is that the text moves past the cell.

Comment: I put in both your suggestions at `cellForRow` and `heightForRow`. Unfortunately, the cells now behave inconsistently, with some contracting, and some staying the same height while the label grows longer.

Answer (score 0):

Try autoresizing:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  VenueReviewCell *cell = (VenueReviewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  cell.commentLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
  cell.commentLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

  return cell;
}
```

Comment: @zack_falcon, something wrong with your code. Pls, share it.

Comment: Added the cellForRowAtIndexPath in the question.

Comment: @zack_falcon, something wrong with your layout. It will be cool if you upload your whole project (this VC with xibs at least). So I'll be able to examine it in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to continue using autolayout:

-set the numberOfLines to '0'

-Implement the following two TableView methods

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

[Working with Self-Sizing Table View Cells](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithSelf-SizingTableViewCells.html) Here is a useful reference.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using manual layout then you must set the `numberOfLines` property of your label to 0, also you will want to call `-sizeToFit` on the label after setting the text.
You might also need to change some other frames after this accordingly so the label doesn't overlap anything.

If you are using AutoLayout then setting the `numberOfLines` is still needed but then it depends on your constraints, if you've set the left and right of the label to the super view's left and right then it can infer a maximum width and grow the label vertically.

In any case your screenshot clearly shows that the label is set to have `numberOfLines = 1`,  your cell height looks okay, which is expected since you're calculating that in code with a set width. It's the rendering of the label which is not being triggered. Change `numberOfLines` to 0 to start with, then in `layoutSubviews` (if you're doing things manually) you'll want to `sizeToFit`

Comment: The table cell does use the AutoLayout, but the only constraints I see are the ones in the code, used merely to change the sizes. There also isn't any layoutSubviews, other than adding subviews.